# How to do a redirect in php from a root url to another without getting a redirect error

Tags: php, xampp

currently I am trying to make my own website that functions in a way like a wiki. I am using the XAMPP installer to create it, and I formatted the index.php file to redirect to a request file without any errors:
`http://localhost/site/request.php`

The request file, as the name suggests, is the file where a request is made in the url, such as a value, etc, which would correspond to what file/page the user is looking for. However one thing that I would like to do is if the request is empty, it will redirect to the main page:
`http://localhost/site/request.php?Main_Pages:Main_Page`
Main_Pages being the type of page that the user wants to see, while Main_Page being the specific page of that type.
Anyways, I tried doing this by inputting this piece of code in the request.php file:

```
$url = 'http://' . $_SERVER['SERVER_NAME'] . $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'];

if ($url = 'http://localhost/site/request.php') {
  header('Location: http://localhost/site/request.php?Main_Pages:Main_Page');
  exit;
}
```

However when I try reloading the page, it redirects to that address successfully, but it gives me the browser error:
`ERR_TOO_MANY_REDIRECTS`

If you guys could help me that would be great, Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is the configuration set up on XAMPP correctly to allow redirects? Can you share the `site/request.php` code to also show us what is happening on that page?

One more thing, your code says:

```
...
if ($url = 'http://localhost/site/request.php') {
...
```

which will be TRUE every time. You only have one =, it needs to be:

```
...
if ($url == 'http://localhost/site/request.php') {
...
```

if you plan on checking the actual value.

Comment: That was the fix! Thank you so much! I didn't put the rest of the code because it had nothing to do with the url and what this code was doing. Specifically it was importing a database configuration file, a template page file, defining the page title and contents, etc, but yeah you're right it would have been better if I did. Again thank you for your help and have a good rest of your day!